# Help needed understanding candlestick pattern formula

Tags: technical-analysis

I have a list of formulas for calculating candlestick patterns.

There are a few expressions that I do not know the meaning of.

Here is an example:

**Bullish Engulfing**

```
O1 > C1 AND 10 * (C - O) >= 7 * (H - L) AND C > O1 AND  C1 > O AND 10 * (H - L) >= 12 * (AVGH10 - AVGL10)
```

At the very end of the formula `12 * (AVGH10 - AVGL10)` what does `AVGH10` and `AVGL10` mean?

More specifically what does the number 10 represent?

Candles? Or is it just an arbitrary number?

If it is just a number the expression would result in a 0 since we have an average of a single number which would be the number itself,
so we would end up with 12 * (10 - 10) = 0. So that can't be it.

In another example:

**Meeting Lines**

```
C1 < O1 AND H1 - L1 > AVGH21.1 - AVGL21.1 AND O1 < MINL3.3 AND C > O AND 100 * ABS(C / C1 - 1) < 1
```

Here `AVGH` and `AVGL` are floating numbers.

Additionaly there is also `MINL3.3`. What does `MINL3.3` mean?

Bonus question

**Doji Dragonfly**

```
50 * ABS(O - C) <= H - L AND STOC1 >= 70 AND H - L >= AVGH10 - AVGL10 AND L = MINL10
```

What is `STOC1`?

[Formulas soruce](https://help.tc2000.com/m/69445/l/800589-bullish-candlestick-patterns-formulas-table)

---

Well the answer is partly in the documentation

AVGH10, 10 stands for the previous 10 candles.

STOC1 stands for the value of the 1st line of the Simple Stochastic oscillator

The floating numbers in expressions like AVGH20.1 remain a mystery

Comment: The source of these formulas?

Comment: This question is most likely off-topic but the [Personal Criteria Formula Syntax Table](https://help.tc2000.com/m/69445/l/745531-personal-criteria-formula-syntax-table) looks like a good starting point

Answer (score 1):

As provided by @0xFEE1DEAD, the [Personal Criteria Formula Syntax Table](https://help.tc2000.com/m/69445/l/745531-personal-criteria-formula-syntax-table) contains the answers.

The explanation for AVGH20.1 can be found under the second "Simple Moving Average" in the list:

w equals the O, H, L, C, or V,
x equals the Period
z equals the Offset

Google to see if there is a TC2000 or Worden chat site bulletin board available.  If so, you'd likely get faster and better answers from other TC2000 users.